# Where can I fund a Windows OS GUI interface that would be a file manager to results output from the GNU find command?

Tags: file-management, command-line

I am very adept at using the GNU (Unix / Linux) find command.

Now I am looking for a GUI UI tool where I can run any find command I want, or point it to a script and have the results displayed in a file manager.

For example, when I run find, I can then open in vi and cycle through the files:

`$find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec vi {} \;`

and cycle through them, but I need a **two paned file manager** (source destination) so that I can double click and open the file in notepad, edit, save or move to a folder in the destination pane.

---

I'm not aware of any product out there with a GUI where I can run GNU find commands.

Nothing really beats GNU find for finding files.

---

I do not need GUI or mouse click help creating a **find** command, but rather viewing the results in a modern file manager.

On Windows, I use **cygwin** with **find.exe** (GNU find).

One solution, if there is such a thing in the Linux world, I may be able to run under WSL and point the find command search directories to the Windows OS directories.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary directory. In this directory, for every found file create a link. Then open this directory in any file manager of your choice, e.g. in [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io), it works well on Linux as well as on Windows.

Since the result of the "find" command can contain multiple files with the same name, it is up to you to create different link names for such files. E.g. you may want to append an index to the link name, or you can add some element of the path, or something else. Since you are *"very adept at using the GNU"*, I suppose this will not be a problem for you.